# Automapper unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I'm new in AutoMapper and I have problem with mapping my generic class to generic dto (using AutoMapper). I have this class:

```
public class Document<T>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Tag[] Tags { get; set; }
    public T? Data { get; set; }
}
```

and this dto:

```
public class DocumentDto<T>
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
    public T? Data { get; set; }
}
```

and I need to make two-way mapping.. I created mapper profile in which I define this mapping like this:

```
public MapperProfile()
{
    CreateMap<Document<FinancialReport>, DocumentDto<FinancialReportDto>>()
            .ForMember(docDto => docDto.Tags, opt => opt.MapFrom(doc => doc.Tags.Select(tag => tag.Value).ToArray()));

    CreateMap<DocumentDto<FinancialReportDto>, Document<FinancialReport>>()
            .ForMember(docDto => docDto.Tags, opt => opt.MapFrom(doc => doc.Tags.Select(tag => new Tag { Value = tag }).ToArray()));

}
```

And then I setting this profile in extension method for dependency injection for IMapper:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddAutoMapper(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(sp =>
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.AddProfile<MapperProfile>();
        });

        return config.CreateMapper();
    });

    return services;
}
```

And after this all when I try remap from DocumentDto=>Document or vice versa I got error: AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

I tryed googled for hours but nothing helped... Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE 1:
I'm calling mapping like this:

```
 public async Task<IResponse> UpdateFinancialReport(DocumentDto<FinancialReportDto> documentDto)
 {

        var doc = _mapper.Map<Document<FinancialReport>>(documentDto);
 }
```

Comment: can you share the code which tries to convert the document to dto and vice versa ?

Comment: @Chetan I editted end of post ;)

Comment: Can you provide the complete exception message for debugging purpose? Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: 'Error mapping types.'
Inner exception:
AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

That's all what I get..

Comment: Looks like the issue occurs while mapper is trying to convert `Data` property  because mapping configuration is missing for `FinancialReportDto` and `FinancialReport`.  So either you need to configure mapping for them or you should ignore converting `Data` property by doing `.ForAllOtherMembers(opts => opts.Ignore());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the problem.. In MapperProfile I was missing mapping config for generic types:

```
CreateMap<FinancialReport, FinancialReportDto>()
            .ReverseMap();
```